# Django - How to set default ordering on ManyToMany field queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-managers, drf-queryset

I have following models:

```
class Hashtag(models.Model):
    ...
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ...

class Tweet(models.Model):
    ...
    hashtags = models.ManyToManyField(
        to='Hashtag',
        through='TweetHashtag',
        through_fields=('tweet', 'hashtag'),
    )
    ...


class TweetHashtag(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(
        to='Tweet',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    hashtag = models.ForeignKey(
        to='Hashtag',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="tweets"
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My problem is when I get a Tweet, I want to get hashtags order by created.

```
tweet = Tweet.objects.get(id=1)
hashtags = list(tweet.hashtags.all())
```

When I check `hashtags`, I see the hashtags are in incorrect ordering. I want to get `tweet.hashtags` order by `through_model.created` (`created` of `TweetHashtag` model.)

Is there anyway?
I have one idea but I don't know how to do that. The idea is to override relation manager of `hashtags` in Tweet model.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

You can order the `HashTag`s with [**`.order_by(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
tweet = Tweet.objects.get(id=1)
hashtags = list(tweet.hashtags.order_by('tweethashtag__created'))
```

Comment: I need to set this `tweethashtag__created` as default ordering of the `tweet.hashtags.all()`. Is it possible?

Comment: @msln: no, you can not specify a default ordering: the ordering of the through model is ignored when accessing the items of a `ManyToManyField`.